# Removing selected item in select2 not updating val()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a input control using as multiselection select2

```
 <input class="form-control no-padding cTagID" tabindex="3" id="cTagID" name="cTagID" style="border:none;" />
```

I convert it to select2 and get data from ajax as below

```
 $("#cTagID").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a Tag",
            allowClear: true,
            width: '100%',
            multiple: true,
            maximumSelectionSize: 9,
            escapeMarkup: function (text) { return text; },
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller")',
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 0,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term,
                        page: page,
                        listType: "mytype",
                        Searchterms: $("#iProjectId").val()
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    var more = (page * 30) < data.total_count; // whether or not there are more results available
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.text,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        }),
                        more: more
                    }
                },
                cache: true
            }
        }).on("change", function () {

            $(this).valid();
            alert($("#cTagID").val()) // Problem is here ..Even if a selected item is removed by user it will still be available in val
        });
```

Ajax call filter and pagination etc is working fine and I get data in below format

```
{ 
   "total_count":6905,
   "items":[ 
      { 
         "id":"(DB-227)-Q14-SL03        ",
         "text":"(DB-227)-Q14-SL03         ~ E_ELOOP                  "
      },
      { 
         "id":"(DB-227)-Q14-SL04        ",
         "text":"(DB-227)-Q14-SL04         ~ E_ELOOP                  "
      },
      { 
         "id":"011100-727               ",
         "text":"011100-727                ~ E_OTP                    "
      },

   ]
}
```

The issue is if user select an item and then removes it it will remain as the val  ("#cTagID").val() will return the removed item also

Comment: have a look at the url: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections  . Add "$(this).trigger('change');" after the statement "$(this).valid();" and then after try to get value of a dropdown. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Researching the Select2.js Script. I found that select2 trims the id field when displaying the selected item. But the Value remains untrimmed .So when removing a selected item select2 tries to remove the item with trimmed id. but will not find it as it doesnt match with any value.

N.B : its always better too use trimmed value  for Id  in your datasource if its string  before assigning to select2